# Automatically installing plugins on QGIS, deploying QGIS plugins on an IT infrastructure

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, deployment

My company is preparing a default QGIS configuration file (*qgis_global_settings.ini*) for deploying on a great number of MS Windows workstations.

We have selected a few QGIS plugins we want to be available on each worktations.

Is there a way to automatically install these extra plugins when installing QGIS? 
By example, can the API be used for that? 
Can a network directory be shared to share pre-installed plugins between all workstations?

Comment: You can copy plugins directories under the `profiles/default/python/plugins/`.

Comment: That would only add them to the `default` profile which might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

The exact path depends on your QGIS setup but you can add any plugin as "core" plugin to your QGIS installation by copying its extracted directory to `apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins` in the installation directory. E.g. `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.4\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins`.

Then the plugin is installed. For usage the user needs to manually activate it. Updates will be installed to the user's profile and "override" the core plugin version. If updates are uninstalled, the core plugin version is available again. The user can not uninstall that.

## Linux, MacOS

The same is possible on Linux and Mac of course. You will have to find the right directory yourself (and edit this answer please) ;)